# How can I separate two pydantic models into different files when these models have a relationship?

Tags: python, model, backend, fastapi, pydantic

I am using Python 3.11.3 FastAPI and SQLAlchemy.
I have been trying to separate two SQLAlchemy models when these two models have a relationship, but as soon as I separate these models into different files, I get an error even though I import the table that refers to the model.
Is there a way to separate these two models and keep the relationship between them?
It would be very helpful, thank you.

For example this is my code and I would like to separate these two classes into different files keeping the relationship ->

```py
class ToPersona(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'to_persona'

    id_persona = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    fc_nombre = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    
class ToUsuario(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'to_usuario'

    id_usuario = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    fk_id_persona = Column(ForeignKey('to_persona.id_persona'))
    to007_persona = relationship('ToPersona')
```

Comment: Are you asking about Pydantic models (your title) or SQLAlchemy models (your code)? What error do you get when you try to have them in different files?

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone. I have already solved the problem of having two SQLAlchemy models in their own file. Thank you so much for your comments; they were very helpful. And a big thank you to the developers

Comment: You can mark right answer as correct or post your own answer here. It can help other people who has similar issue. This is how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the two models into different files while maintaining the relationship. Here's an example structure:

to_persona.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class ToPersona(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'to_persona'

    id_persona = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    fc_nombre = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
```

to_usuario.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from .to_persona import ToPersona
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class ToUsuario(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'to_usuario'

    id_usuario = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    fk_id_persona = Column(ForeignKey('to_persona.id_persona'))
    to007_persona = relationship(ToPersona)
```

Ensure that the two files (`to_persona.py` and `to_usuario.py`) are in the same directory or are importable from each other. The relationship is maintained by importing the `ToPersona` class from `to_persona.py` in the `to_usuario.py` file. This way, when you define the relationship, it's using the same class that is defined in the other file.

Make sure to adjust the imports and file structure based on your project setup.

Comment: Have you run your code? It seems like it doesn't work..
You are using two different `Base`

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone. I have already solved the problem of having two SQLAlchemy models in their own file. Thank you so much for your comments; they were very helpful. And a big thank you to the developers

Answer (score 0):

db.py

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

to_persona.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from db import Base


class ToPersona(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'to_persona'

    id_persona = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    fc_nombre = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
```

to_usuario.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from to_persona import ToPersona
from db import Base

class ToUsuario(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'to_usuario'

    id_usuario = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    fk_id_persona = Column(ForeignKey('to_persona.id_persona'))
    to007_persona = relationship(ToPersona)
```

main.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from db import Base
from to_usuario import ToUsuario

if __name__ == "__main__":

    engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone. I have already solved the problem of having two SQLAlchemy models in their own file. Thank you so much for your comments; they were very helpful. And a big thank you to the developers